# what is different between FractionalOffset and Alignment in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I m confused about what is different between FractionalOffset and Alignment .. I see them doing the same .. check my example code to understand me :

Example 1:

```
final fractionalOffset = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 16,
      ),
      alignment: FractionalOffset.bottomLeft,
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage("example1"),
        height: 92,
        width: 92,
      ),
    );
```

Example 2:

```
final alignment = Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: 16,
      ),
      alignment: Alignment.bottomLeft,
      child: Image(
        image: AssetImage("example2"),
        height: 92,
        width: 92,
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 6):

Official docs explains very well:

> `FractionalOffset` uses a coordinate system with an `origin in the top-left corner` of the rectangle whereas `Alignment` uses a coordinate system with an `origin in the center` of the rectangle.

Also:

> Historically, FractionalOffset predates Alignment. When we attempted to make a version of FractionalOffset that adapted to the TextDirection, we ran into difficulty because placing the origin in the top-left corner introduced a left-to-right bias that was hard to remove.

In summary, `FractionalOffset` independent from `TextDirection`, where `Alignment` has some relations with.

Examples:

> Alignment(-1.0, -1.0) represents the `top left` of the rectangle.
>
> Alignment(1.0, 1.0) represents the `bottom right` of the rectangle.
>
> FractionalOffset(1.0, 0.0) represents the `top right` of the Size.
>
> FractionalOffset(0.0, 1.0) represents the `bottom left` of the Size.

Comment: Esen Mehmet .. Yes, I know that the documents explain them well .. I checked the official documents before asking my question .. But sometimes I need someone to explain it to me differently for a deeper understanding .. so i hope you understand me now . thank you